# Access 2016 select query repeats field value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to do a query in MS Access 2016 and have three tables like so:

```
BIB_TEXT
BIB_ID          AUTHOR          TITLE
255591          Ratnavi         saha Tamara
459194          Kantaiya        Akam elements
123456          Bob             Rules of Football   

BIB_MASTER
BIB_ID          SUPPRESS_IN_OPAC
255591          N
459194          N
123456          Y

BIB_INDEX
BIB_ID          INDEX_CODE      NORMAL_HEADING
255591          600H            Ilangaratna, 1913-1992
255591          600H            Tamara
459194          600H            Campantar
459194          600H            Tevaram
459194          600H            Cuntarar
459194          600H            Siva in Literature
123456          600H            Football United States
123456          600H            Football Rules
```

What I'm getting:

```
BIB_ID  AUTHOR          TITLE           NORMAL_HEADING
255591  Ratnavi         saha Tamara     Ilangaratna, 1913-1992
255591  Ratnavi         saha Tamara     Ilangaratna, 1913-1992
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Campantar   
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Campantar   
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Campantar   
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Campantar
```

What I want to get:

```
BIB_ID  AUTHOR          TITLE           NORMAL_HEADING
255591  Ratnavi         saha Tamara     Ilangaratna, 1913-1992
255591  Ratnavi         saha Tamara     Tamara
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Campantar   
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Tevaram 
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Cuntarar    
459194  Kantaiya        Akam elements   Siva in Literature
```

I suspect it is something with the joins but I'm not able to get it to pull all of the NORMAL_HEADING values no matter what I change. Here is the SQL:

```
SELECT 
BIB_TEXT.BIB_ID, BIB_TEXT.AUTHOR, BIB_TEXT.TITLE, BIB_INDEX.NORMAL_HEADING
FROM 
(BIB_TEXT INNER JOIN BIB_MASTER ON BIB_TEXT.BIB_ID = BIB_MASTER.BIB_ID) INNER JOIN BIB_INDEX ON BIB_MASTER.BIB_ID = BIB_INDEX.BIB_ID
WHERE 
(((BIB_INDEX.INDEX_CODE)="600H") AND ((BIB_MASTER.SUPPRESS_IN_OPAC)="N"));
```

Any advice you have would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: I cannot test immediately but I do not see how you get repeating *NORMAL_HEADING* with this data if *BIB_ID* is unique in first two tables. Carefully check original data.

Comment: I built tables with data shown and copy/pasted the query. Works just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. I will double-check all the data. Is it possible that the underlying database being Oracle with an odbc connection be affecting this?